# about "Inputscope Number" Keyboard. I need "Enter" button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

In XAML's Textbox, I use [Inputscope = "Number"]

And sometimes I think If Number keyboard have "Enter" button , it's more Useful.

Is there any "Number + Enter" keyboard in WP8.1?

It's my "Ideal Number Keyboard" Image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that, the access access to the keyboard is restricted. Either you go for alphanumeric  keyboard  and handle alphabets in your textchanged events or create a custom look-a-like of the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Cirag Shar, I appreciate that.